# I,J be nonzero ideal in a domain R,show that I∩J nonezero

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

let I,J be nonzero ideal in a domain R,show that I $\cap$ J$\neq {0}$

my attempt,for any two ideals,there is a isomorphic
\begin{equation*}
          \frac{I}{(I\cap J)}\cong \frac{(I+J)}{J}
\end{equation*}
so,if $I\cap J={0}$,then $I\cong \frac{(I+J)}{J}$ by $a\rightarrow a+J$.How can I get a contradiction.

Comment: To be precise, every ideal of every ring is nonempty. You mean "nontrivial".

Comment: Hint: pick nonzero elements $x \in I$ and $y \in J$. Can you construct an element of the ring which must be in $I \cap J$?

Comment: IJ$\subset$ I$\cap$J,so xy$\in I\cap J$. - @diracdeltafunk

Comment: Exactly, and you just need to prove that $xy$ is nonzero (since $R$ is a domain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $I \cap J$ is *never* empty, since every ideal contains $0$.  What is wanted here is $I \cap J \ne \{0\}$, the trivial or zero ideal, thusly:

I assume by "domain" our OP means "integral domain"; then $R$ is a commutative ring such that

$\forall 0 \ne x, y \in R, \; xy \ne 0; \tag 1$

this of course yields

$xy = 0 \Longrightarrow [x = 0] \vee [y = 0]; \tag 2$

that is, a product is only zero when one of the factors vanishes.

Now with $I$, $J$ non-trivial ideals such that

$I \cap J = \{0\}, \tag 3$

then since

$0 \ne i \in I, 0 \ne j \in J \Longrightarrow ij \in I \cap J, \tag 4$

in accord with (3)

$ij = 0; \tag 5$

but by (2) this implies at least one of $i$, $j$ vanishes, contradicting (4).  Thus (3) is false and

$I \cap J \ne \{0\}. \tag 6$

Comment: thank you ,now i hnow how to do it

Comment: @Yunhao:  glad to be of service; if you find the answer truly helpful, you might consider "accepting" it with the green check-mark.  Cheers!